MongoDB schema: optional vs. nullable
If I have a schema that includes fields that may or may not be set, what is the best way to handle these fields? Should they be optional or instead nullable?
Here an example (Mongoose/NestJs)
@Schema()
class MySchema {
  @Prop({ required: true )
  classification: string;

  @Prop({ default: null })
  nullableProperty: string | null;

  @Prop()
  optionalProperty?: string;
}

Is one way always better than the other or are there some guidelines, which option may be better in certain situations?

Would this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16555388/3723423 ?

When inserting a new record,
either you think there's a good chance the
optional property will be defined in a subsequent update,
or you think it likely that it shall never be defined.
For records that get updated later,
setting an initial null value plays a little nicer
with the auto padding adjustments made by the engine.
It's a subtle point you can likely ignore.
From now on, let's assume that "missing when created"
tends to imply "always missing" over the record's lifetime.
Rather than define a null value, prefer to omit it.
@vinipsmaker explains
it this way:

I'd save documents without the field, because the operators will continue to work as expected and I'd save some space.

